# Java game in slick fps extremely high

Tags: java, frame-rate, slick2d

I am creating game in Java using Slick, but there is a problem when I upload and run it on my www as an applet. The FPS are extremely high, even when I put some limit on it in my code.

```
MainWindow.setTargetFrameRate(60);
```

When I run the game on my notebook, it works fine, maxium fps is 60, but on my website it is between 800-1000 which is just crazy. I've tested it on chrome & firefox, both failed.

Anyone ?

Comment: Do you have permission for that operation? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: In is in main method, in throwing SlickException

Comment: In that case please add the exception details (type, message, stack trace) to your question above.